# What is enclosing variable in java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

What does it mean by enclosing class and enclosing the variable in the context of `inner-classes` in `java`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class

Comment: This would be easier in the context. Without it it’s hard to tell what that book means exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enclosing class** means in which inner-class is defined. So all the variables defined in the outer class are known as **Enclosing variable**

```
class Outer { <-- Enclosing class
    private int age; <-- Enclosing variable
    private int name; <-- Enclosing variable

    class Inner {
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your examples. if i am declaring a variable inside Inner class then can i say local variable and another question what doesn't mean outter class? is it same as enclosing class?

Comment: No *local variable* is a term that already has another definition. *outer class*  and *enclosing class* mean the same.